# Functional form assumption and identifying assumption in regressions

Tags: regression

I am confused about the number and the type of assumptions I am imposing
when running a regression.

Consider the following situation. I have data on individuals' efficiency
when performing a number of tasks at various points in time. Let $E_{i,t}^{k}$
be individual $i$'s efficency at time $t$ in performing task $k$.

This is a study about the tasks. The hypothesis is that the tasks are
related and to study this relationship I run the following regressions (for
each $k=1,...,K$)
\begin{equation}
E_{i,t}^{k}=\sum_{l=1,l\not=k}^{K}\beta ^{lk}E_{i,t}^{l}+\delta
_{i}^{k}+\delta _{t}^{k}+\eta _{i,t}^{k}
\end{equation}
where the coefficients $\beta ^{lk}$ are the parameters of interest, $\delta _{i}^{k}$ is an individual-fixed-effect,  $\delta
_{t}^{k}$ a time-fixed-effect and $\eta _{i,t}^{k}$ is an error term.

The first assumption I am imposing is the functional form given above. But is this the only assumption I am imposing? The functional form
says nothing about minimizing the squared residuals. So I assume I am
imposing more than one assumption. Is this an "identifying
assumption"?

Comment: Please tell us more about those "error terms."  Unless you make some assumptions about them, too, how could you know what your model is saying?

Comment: @whuber Ok, thanks. This already helps. I assume that the efficiencies ($E_{i,t}^{l}$) on the right hand side of the equation are uncorrelated with the error term ($\eta _{i,t}^{k}$). I also assume that the efficiencies ($E_{i,1}^{k},...,E_{i,T}^{k}$) are i.i.d. over individuals. Since all (left hand and right hand side) $E_{i,t}^{k}$ are endogenous, I do not interpret the coefficients in a causal way.